# ASP.NET MVC return PartialViewResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I made a form with `@using(Ajax.BeginForm){}`. It posts to a method in my controller that returns a PartialViewResult. It works fine when everything is valid, but what should I return if 
it's not (e.g., the modelstate is not valid)?
**How Ajax.BeginForm can manage the error? What I return to manage the Failure?**

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Room", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST",
UpdateTargetId="formRoom", InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace, onFailure =??})) {

public PartialViewResult Create(Movie mov)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Save(mov);
            return PartialView("CreateResult", mov);
        }
        return null;            
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may return another View.

e.g. `return PartialView("MyErrorView");`

Comment: For Ajax Calls you can also return JSON like "return Json(new { Result = "Failure", Message = "Model Invalid"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); and parse this result in the success/failure ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Just return Create action with the model to display the errors (the same as you returned on your get):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult PartialCreate(Album album)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Albums.Add(album);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
        return PartialView(album);
    }
```

Comment: you cannot return that, you cannot convert it. Try to compile it.

Comment: Just made a sample. It compiles without any errors. Or is it because the Ajax.BeginForm? I'll try that as well.

Comment: before you put return View();

Comment: ah, sorry, that was because I didn't see in the first place that you used a PartialView. I had already changed it when you added your comment. Does it work now?

Comment: yes... but I just edit my question... that was not what I intend to ask

Comment: You still return null. Why not the model? Why does the client validation not kick in?